# libtool command not found

Tags: c, linux, makefile, libtool

Hi i am trying to build my project in linux. The build procedure is configure, make and make install.
During make i am getting error from libtool as shown below. I am not getting what is the reason for this. Please help me with this.

```
../../libtool: line 445:: command not found
../../libtool: line 448:: command not found
../../libtool: line 453:: command not found
../../libtool: line 474:: command not found
../../libtool: line 523:: command not found
../../libtool: line 529:: command not found
../../libtool: line 539: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
../../libtool: line 539: `  case `(set -o) 2>/dev/null` in *posix*) set -o posix;; esac
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to run `libtoolize` in the folder `../../`

Comment: what command it is trying to run on line 445 would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

At the end of line 445 in the file `libtool.c` maybe there is a `^M`. In order to build, this has to be deleted.